# Fatal bug in all versions after 2.2.0 of GoogleMaps SDK for iOS

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I created an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112233560) half a year ago, but nothing has happened.
One of our apps has a foreign letter in its name (because it's a local norwegian app).
If I have Google Maps SDK for iOS installed with version 2.3.0 or later, the app instantly crashes when opening a map. The SDK is currently at 2.7.0, which still has the same issue.
I can only use 2.2.0 or earlier when I have a foreign letter in the product name.

If any of you reading this are using Google Maps for iOS, can you try adding the letter Ø to your product name, and see if the app crashes when showing an app?

What should I do? I've been stuck on 2.2.0 for a looong time, and the google support team won't answer me..

Comment: Thanks Google.. .Yea I would seriously consider renaming the App without that letter. Yes I know... its shit for everybody... but what you gonna do? You could try and look at the source code of SDK, Android???? If there is any and try and fix it your self.

Comment: Renaming is not an option. This is a huge public/official/governmental brand, and it's the same name as the entire county.

Comment: Well then escalate the issue to somebody high up, a CTO of some public body, get them to contact Google via a public route and get them talking to the right people. Your bug is probably so low priority that nobody has even saw it. Since this effects the whole country then you need to get officials pushing Google. Firstly security concerns that you are blocked from upgrading, second usability that for some reason they regressed from 2.2.0 ...